# Concentating a matrix with a function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix K with a certain function

My code is as follows

```
K=zeros(360*360,3);
for m = 0:360
    for n = 0:360
        for d=0:5
            U1(1,1)= cos(m)+cos(m+n);
            U1(1,2)= sin(m)+sin(m+n);
            U1(1,3)=-d;
            K(m,n)=(U1);

        end
    end
end
```

However I keep getting an error, "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Can somebody explain how this can be fixed?

Comment: you get the error because `m` and `n` start from `0`, they should start from `1`.

Comment: Hi @Kamtal Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
 is the error I get when I change m and n start from 1.

Comment: @Trippy: That's because of `K(m,n)=(U1);`. See my answer below.

Comment: you also need to do `K=zeros([360,360,3]);` and `K(m,n,:)=U1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K is a (360^2)x3 matrix here. What you're trying to do seems to be:

```
K(m*n, :) = U1;
```

There would also be a problem here since your `m` & `n` start from `0`, not `1`.

I would rather do the following:

```
K = zeros(360, 360, 3);
for m = 1:360
    for n = 1:360
        for d = 0:5
            K(m, n, 1) = cos(m) + cos(m+n);
            K(m, n, 2) = sin(m) + sin(m+n);
            K(m, n, 3) = -d;
        end
    end
end
```

This would give you a 360x360x3 3D matrix where m & n directly index into the structure.

### EDIT

Based on @Trippy's comment below, the code would need to be modified as follows:

```
K = zeros(360*360, 3);
for m = 0:359
    for n = 1:360
        for d = 0:5
            K(m*360 + n, 1) = cos(m) + cos(m+n);
            K(m*360 + n, 2) = sin(m) + sin(m+n);
            K(m*360 + n, 3) = -d;
        end
    end
end
```

This would fill in the matrix K in row-major form, which I'm assuming is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to generate a (360^2,3) matrix with each row being one solution of U1.

Comment: The final idea is to plot each row of K on a 3d plot.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Would you be able to explain what I was doing wrong earlier? @Roney Michael

Comment: @Trippy: The key is that the matrix indices were incorrect. Try a simple example replacing 360 with 3 and (359 with 2).

Comment: @Trippy: On a side note, the `sin` and `cos` functions in matlab operate on radian input, not degrees. You'll need to map degrees to radians if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Roney. Much appreciated and yes, I fixed the sin and cos issue.